# Stored functions in MySQL not working (invalid use of groupby)

Tags: mysql, group-by, stored-functions

Hi all I started learning functions in MySQL and I am trying different things. I created this function below, that should return the count of different departments/titles
however I am getting an error on the group by part when I call the select statement

```
DELIMITER //


CREATE function num_of_titles(titles_ varchar(80)) returns char deterministic

    return count(titles_);
// DELIMITER ;

select  title, num_of_titles(title) as count_title from titles
group by 1;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bk1dx.png)

Comment: Don't be so lazy.  What's so hard about typing the column name `title` rather than `1`.

Comment: The function definition is invalid.  The usage of the COUNT aggregate function (as shown in the code example) is invalid. (We are assuming that the intent here is a  reference to the builtin COUNT() aggregate function, and not an attempt to call to a user-defined function named "count")

Comment: what could be the possible solution than in order to get the count of the titles. I want to see how can we apply the count inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The

```
return count(titles_);
```

is not valid SQL. `COUNT`-function cannot be used alone, only as part of a proper SQL query.